# How to map a keyboard to a console in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, usb, tty

I am bringing up linux on an an ARM board.

I have a screen connected and working, it boots up to a login prompt on tty1

I have a USB keyboard that, I believe, is being recognized as a input device.

How do I tell Linux to use the usb keyboard for input on tty1?
I played with stty for an hour, but I'm not sure this is it.
Is there some Udev rule I need to configure?

thanks

**EDIT**

Here is a dump of my kernel log; this is when I pull the plug:

```
[56234.757446] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[56234.765391] evbug: Event. Dev: input0, Type: 0, Code: 0, Value: 1
[56234.769276] evbug: Disconnected device: input0
```

This is when I plug it back in.

```
[56238.339500] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[56238.949462] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[56239.069499] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ci_hdrc
[56239.248248] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=1203
[56239.255036] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[56239.406428] usbhid 1-1:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
[56239.411605] usbhid: probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -71
[56239.478370] input: HID 04d9:1203 as /devices/soc.1/70000000.aips/73f80000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1203.0002/input/input1
[56239.492158] evbug: Connected device: input1 (HID 04d9:1203 at usb-ci_hdrc.0-1/input1)
[56239.492754] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1203.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 04d9:1203] on usb-ci_hdrc.0-1/input1
```

I'm not sure what the error -71 is all about, I can't seem to find that error number in the source (kernel 3.15)
. But it still appears to have succeeded as being recognized as an input device.

Further, when I plug/unplug the keyboard the screen blanking ends and I see the text again.  This to me would imply that something is being recognized as an input device.
And, sysfs recognizes it has a keyboard input device... at least that's what I think this means:

```
arm:/sys/devices/soc.1/70000000.aips/73f80000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:04D9:1203.0003/input/input2/capabilities# cat key
2000000 39fa d941d001 1e0000 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all all try to make sure that the keyboard is really recognized as input device (watching the kernel boot log or call `dmesg` on a serial console, etc.) Chances are that that either the USB host or maybe even the keyboard input support is not enabled in your kernel config.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been a problem within the kernel.  There must have been a missing feature.  The requirement for having a keyboard has been dropped, and so I am not following up on this.